# Invisible Recaptcha - site key not loaded?

Tags: javascript, invisible-recaptcha

Updating because I have changed the implementation to something (somewhat) more successful.

I'm trying to implement the Invisible Recaptcha in our system. We are using dynamically generated forms, so, I'm going the route of programmatically invoking the challenge. I have this code to get the API:

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Just before drawing my form, I inject the captcha `div`:

```
form.fields.push({
    html: '<div id="g-recaptcha-div" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<mykey>" data-callback="myCallback" data-size="invisible"></div>',
    type: 'html'
});
```

When my form is drawn, I then call the render function:

```
recaptcha_id = grecaptcha.render(
    'g-recaptcha-div',
    {
        'data-callback': _settings.form.submit
    }
);
```

When the form appears, he "protected by reCAPTCHA" logo box shows up over my submit button.

In my submit function, I do some form validation, and then 'execute' the reCaptcha:

```
grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_id);
```

And then continue on with my submit. So far, exactly once I have seen the reCaptcha challenge ('pick out images with a storefront'), at which point the `g-recaptcha-response` value was inserted into my form submission, and I see it in the parameters passed to my `PHP` function.

But, most of the time I do not see the challenge, and there is nothing in the `g-recaptcha-response` parameter, so my `PHP` validation fails. A couple of questions:

1) My assumption about the challenge not showing up all the time is that the Google logic only requires it when "conditions are right". If that is the case, what am I to do when it doesn't show up, at which point the `g-recaptcha-response` parameter is there with no value - do I just ignore it at that point, assuming that no value means ok?

2) Is there any way to "force" the challenge to show up, if only to make me feel better about the whole thing working, and to test my handling of a response?

3) I have tried calling `grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha_id)` after `grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_id)`, but that doesn't return anything. It would be easier/better for me to process the reCaptcha in my client.

Any answers appreciated. I may resubmit this as a new 'Question' since this one has been around a while.